# CSS grid fallback

Tags: html, css, grid

Is it possible to replace a 3 column `grid` with alternative css for older browsers? I dont want to use bootstrap or similar grid framework. Can this be done with regular css using `inline-block` or similar?

My css with feature query is like this:

```
@supports (display: grid) {
.skillsContainer {
   width: 700px;
   margin: auto;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
   grid-gap: 35px;
   padding: 60px 0;
}

.skills div {
   color: #fff;
   border-radius: 5px;
   padding: 20px;
   font-size: 150%;
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
  <div className="skillsContainer">
          <div> 
            <span className="chart" data-percent="10"> 
              <span className="percent">number</span> 
            </span>
            <h4>HTML5</h4>
          </div>
          <div> 
            <span className="chart" data-percent="10"> 
              <span className="percent">number</span> 
            </span>
            <h4>CSS3</h4>
          </div>
          <div> 
            <span className="chart" data-percent="10">
              <span className="percent">number</span> 
            </span>
            <h4>ReactJs</h4>
          </div>
          <div> 
            <span className="chart" data-percent="75">
              <span className="percent">number</span> 
            </span>
            <h4>jQuery</h4>
          </div>
          <div> 
            <span className="chart" data-percent="10"> 
              <span className="percent">number</span> 
            </span>
            <h4>WordPress</h4>
          </div>
          <div> 
            <span className="chart" data-percent="10"> 
              <span className="percent">number</span> 
            </span>
            <h4>Fireworks</h4>
          </div>    
      </div>
```

Comment: you can give a try to column-count and column-width ... would require prefix for some browser ... or float + clear every 3 elements ....  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mWGmXE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for only dropping a link, but this article actually explains it pretty well:

[Browser Compatibility for CSS Grid Layouts with Simple Sass Mixins](https://css-tricks.com/browser-compatibility-css-grid-layouts-simple-sass-mixins/)

The gist of it is:

```
display: -ms-grid;
-ms-grid-columns: ???;
-ms-grid-rows: ???;
```

and also:

```
@mixin grid-child ($col-start, $col-end, $row-start, $row-end) {
    -ms-grid-column: $col-start;
    -ms-grid-column-span: $col-end - $col-start;
    -ms-grid-row: $row-start;
    -ms-grid-row-span: $row-end - $row-start;
    grid-column: #{$col-start}/#{$col-end};
    grid-row: #{$row-start}/#{$row-end};
}
.child {
    @include grid-child(2, 3, 2, 3);
}
```